# ssh session not terminated at reboot/halt from putty after upgrade to 14.04

Tags: 14.04, ssh

After my server upgrade to ubuntu 14.04 when i do reboot or halt from putty, server reboots normaly but ssh session is not terminated by the server as before the upgrade. Can anybody help? Thank you!

Comment: What happens after you enter `reboot`? Are commands still executed? How can you tell that the server has rebooted? What is the output of `uptime` directly after the reboot?

Comment: Do you mean the connection from PuTTY client is like 'dead' and not terminated by the server? If so, it may be related to a faster init system which boots faster (dependency based), but also shuts down services faster on shut down or reboot. It may cause that the network is down before SSH server gets terminated, resulting in your SSH client never seeing the (graceful) connection termination. Just a guess, may provide a clue for an answer.

Comment: yes is like  'dead ' and not terminated by the server! How can i fix that again?

Comment: @John Found it, now writing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Background information

Ubuntu changed to Upstart as the init system, from System-V. It's a lot faster, by enabling parallel starting/stopping services, decreasing boot times significantly. Services are depending on each other sometimes, for which System-V had a fixed order of starting/stopping them for each runlevel. For Upstart, the dependencies are declarative, like "start firewall before the network is brought up", which will make sure the network isn't started before the firewall is finished. Other services without this dependency can already start, this way.

#### Change SSH Upstart configuration

By default SSH Upstart init configuration in Ubuntu 14.04 does not have any dependency on other services, so it may be brought after the network was shut down. This may cause a dead connection on your clients, because the SSH server won't be able to reach the clients in some occasions.

Add a dependency in the `/etc/init/ssh.conf` (SSH Upstart init configuration):

Under

```
stop on runlevel [!2345]
```

add

```
stop on stopping networking
```

Assuming you do not user network manager, but regular `/etc/network/interfaces` networking configuration, this will make sure the SSH daemon will be shut down before the network is.

*Note: untested, please verify.*

You may want to report this as a bug against the `openssh-server` package. I think it will be an improvement for Ubuntu to have a proper dependency on the SSH init configuration.

Comment: @ gertvdijk Unfortunately this has no effect on my system - also found that even the bash history IS not saved when rebooting. thank you!

Comment: @John Did you test this solely on one reboot after editing the file? It may be required to boot with the newly edited ssh.conf before a shutdown will be done correctly. Also, more requirements for your network may be a dependency. E.g. a VPN. I don't have access to your machine and you don't describe anything about that in your question, so it's hard to guess what the missing dependency is here.

Comment: @ gertvdijk I tested with 2 repeated reboots after the ssh.conf edit - no change. I am on local network with no any firewalls or anything else. My server has two network interfaces eth0 and tun0 for openvpn.Thanks!

Comment: @John Ah okay. This requires further testing then. For anyone reading this answer, I think we're almost there, feel free to edit/improve.